# Only remove/Exclude an attribute from json if it exists

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I have following JSON and I would like to remove streets from the JSON object if only it exists under Address which is an array. I am trying to do this in powershell. I can get my script working and remove the streets but I only want to run the exclude line of command if the address has the streets property. Is that possible?

```
{
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "123"
    }],
    "Nationality": [{
        "name": "US",
        "id": "456"
    }],
    "address": [{
            "$type": "Home",
            "name": "Houston",
            "streets": [{
                "name": "Union",
                "postalCode": "10"
            }]
        },
        {
            "$type": "Home5",
            "name": "Houston5"
        },
        {
            "$type": "Office",
            "name": "Hawai",
            "streets": [{
                "name": "Rock",
                "postalCode": "11"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Powershell script

```
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path "Test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
#Only want to run for address objects that contains streets
$FileContent.address = $FileContent.address | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets #Only would like to run if object address has streets property
$FileContent | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: @mklement0 I want to remove partitions in a loop. Address object is an array and it can have streets or it might not have it. So I only want to run the select object and exclude the streets if it has it.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, Let me add a new question with two different JSON, one with streets and one without and I will send you that question

Comment: @mklement0 Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64227185/exclude-the-json-property-only-if-it-exists-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- This answer performs the same operation as in the question, only more succinctly, in a single pipeline.
- It is benign to run `Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets` against *all* objects in array `address`, because the call is an effective no-op for those objects that already lack a `streets` property (though a *copy* of such objects is created too).

---

You need an *assignment* to modify your objects *in-place* before outputting them, which requires a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call:

```bsh
Get-Content -Raw Test.json | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [array] $_.address = $_.address | select * -exclude streets; $_ 
  }
```

Note how each object parsed from the JSON input is first modified via the assignment (`$_.address = ...`), and then passed out (`$_`).

A more efficient, but a little more obscure variant:

```bsh
Get-Content -Raw Test.json | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    $_.address.ForEach({ $_.psobject.Properties.Remove('streets') }); $_ 
  }
```

With your sample JSON input, both commands output the following:

```
Customer    Nationality          address
--------    -----------          -------
{@{id=123}} {@{name=US; id=456}} {@{$type=Home; name=Houston}, @{$type=Home5; name=Houston5}, @{$type=Office; name=Hawai}}
```

Note how the objects in the `address` column no longer have a `streets` property.

**Caveat**: Note that **[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)** limits the serialization depth to `2` by default, which is sufficient in *this* case, but in other cases **you may have to pass a `-Depth` argument to prevent data loss** - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).