# Exclude the JSON property only if it exists - Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I have two different JSONs and I would like to remove streets from the JSON object if only it exists under Address which is an array. I am trying to do this in powershell. I can get my script working and remove the streets but I only want to run the exclude line of command if the address has the streets property.

```
{
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "123"
    }],
    "address": [{
            "$type": "Home",
            "name": "Houston",
            "streets": [{
                "name": "Union",
                "postalCode": "10"
            }]
        },
        {
            "$type": "Office",
            "name": "Hawai",
            "streets": [{
                "name": "Rock",
                "postalCode": "11"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

2nd JSON - Do not want to run the exclude line for 2nd JSON because there are no streets

```
{
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "123"
    }],
    "address": [{
            "$type": "Home",
            "name": "Houston"
        },
        {
            "$type": "Office",
            "name": "Hawai"
        }
    ]
}
```

Powershell script

```
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path "Test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
#Only want to run for address objects that contains streets
$FileContent.address = $FileContent.address | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets #Only run for 1st json and not for 2nd json
$FileContent | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute the code only `if` the `address` has the `member` `streets` you can test for just that:

```
if (
    ($FileContent.address | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "streets") -ne $null
){
    $FileContent.address = $FileContent.address | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty streets
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[T-Me's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64227947/45375) is the most robust approach, because it looks for the presence of the *property itself* rather than non-null *values*.

If you're willing to assume that the absence of a *value* also means the absence of the *property itself*, you can take the following shortcut, which performs better:

```bash
$hasAtLeastOneStreet = 0 -ne
 (@((Get-Content Test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).address.streets) -ne $null).Count
```

`.address.streets` uses [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to extract all `streets` values, `@(...)` ensures that the result is an array, `-ne $null` filters out any `$null` values from that array, and `.Count` counts its elements.

Note: This expression *should* be simpler:
`$null -ne (Get-Content Test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).address.streets`
but due to a *bug* currently cannot - see the bottom section.

To demonstrate (the input strings are compressed, single-line versions of your JSON documents):

```bash
'{"Customer":[{"id":"123"}],"address":[{"$type":"Home","name":"Houston","streets":[{"name":"Union","postalCode":"10"}]},{"$type":"Office","name":"Hawai","streets":[{"name":"Rock","postalCode":"11"}]}]}',
'{"Customer":[{"id":"123"}],"address":[{"$type":"Home","name":"Houston"},{"$type":"Office","name":"Hawai"}]}' | 
  foreach { 
    "has street values: " + 
      (0 -ne @(((ConvertFrom-Json $_).address.streets) -ne $null).Count)
  }
```

The above yields, showing that the first JSON document had `street` values, whereas the second one did not.

```bash
has street values: True
has street values: False
```

---

Note: You *should* be able to simplify the test expression to the following, but this doesn't work due to a *bug* present up to at least PowerShell 7.3.4:

```bash
# !! SHOULD work, but as of PowerShell 7.3.4 DOESN'T, due to a bug 
# !! in how [pscustomobject]s are treated in member-access enumeration.
$null -ne (Get-Content Test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).address.streets
```

Normally, the absence of any `streets` property values should result in `$null`, but with two or more `[pscustomobject]` instances present in the `.address` array, an *array* of `$null` values is unexpectedly returned.

See [GitHub issue #13752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13752).